# Perl: How to use proper data structures:multili line, multiple capture groups

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file:

```
XXGuy:Tom1XXBill1XX<tab>XXBlah2XX\n
XXFriend:Bob1XXcarry:Stuff1XX\n
XXGuy:Tom2XXBill2XX<tab>XXBlah7XX\n
XXFriend:Bob2XXcarry:Stuff2XX\n
```

The content I want to extract is Tom{1,2}, Bob1{1,2}, and Stuff1{1,2} and print:

"Tomx's friend is Bobx and is carrying Stuffx"

I can use a multi-line regex with multiple capture groups and Tomx, Bobx, and Stuffx will be in $1, $2, and $3 and I can print each element out but can't really process them in the way I'd like as described - I don't know how to store into what structure (Array/Hash don't see to fit the bill here?) and retrieve the data.

I'm looking at these posts:

[Perl: Pulling pairs of values from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470189/perl-pulling-pairs-of-values-from-an-array) 
[Finding multiple matches with multiline regex perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372641/finding-multiple-matches-with-multiline-regex-perl)

Suggestions?

Comment: post your regex, please.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you are looking for the `/g` flag in list context, still what you do with the results is the harder part. I would do something like this, I'm not sure its the absolute best way, but it should serve:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = <<'END';
XXGuy:Tom1XXBill1XX XXBlah2XX
XXFriend:Bob1XXcarry:Stuff1XX
XXGuy:Tom2XXBill2XX XXBlah7XX
XXFriend:Bob2XXcarry:Stuff2XX
END

my @data;
push @data, [$1,$2,$3] while $string =~ /(Tom\d+).*?(Bob\d+).*?(Stuff\d+)/msg;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@data;
```

Read more in [perldoc perlretut](http://p3rl.org/retut) and [perldoc perlreref](http://p3rl.org/reref) (or heaven help you [perldoc perlre](http://p3rl.org/perlre))

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that uses named captures on the data:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/:(?<name>.+?)XX.+(?=\t)/) {
        print "$+{name}'s friend is ";
        next;
    }

    /:(?<name>.+?)XX.+:(?<stuff>.+?)XX/;
    print "$+{name} and is carrying $+{stuff}\n";
}

__DATA__
XXGuy:Tom1XXBill1XX XXBlah2XX
XXFriend:Bob1XXcarry:Stuff1XX
XXGuy:Tom2XXBill2XX XXBlah7XX
XXFriend:Bob2XXcarry:Stuff2XX
```

Output:

```
Tom1's friend is Bob1 and is carrying Stuff1
Tom2's friend is Bob2 and is carrying Stuff2
```